# How can I write this math equation in latex?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Here is what I want to write in latex:

[image]

Comment: Could you please show what your code looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! Here's how to write your equation. I added another solution using the command `\bm` from the `bm` package, which allows to write bold italic math.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    With \verb|\mathbf|:    & \( \mathcal{D} = \{ (\mathbf{x}_i, y_i) \}_{i=1}^N \) \\
    With \verb|\bm|:        & \( \mathcal{D} = \{ (\bm{x}_i, y_i) \}_{i=1}^N \) 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\verb|...|` won't work sometimes...

Comment: @Someone Can you precise what you mean? When wouldn't it work?

Comment: Thanks, can I write this only using $$ or is that impossible?

Comment: Defining an env

Comment: @JohnDem Yes, it has to be written in math mode, so between ``$...$`` or ``\(...\)`` for inline math, or between ``\[...\]`` for display math. ``$$...$$`` also works, but [you should avoid using that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: @someone - The \verb isn't really part of the answer; just a cute comment.